# ImportError: cannot import name ResourceError

Tags: python, couchdb, debian

I'm trying to install couchdb app on debian using the following command

```
couchapp push http://user:pass@localhost:5984/acra-appname
```

and I'm having the following error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/restkit/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from restkit.conn import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/restkit/conn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from socketpool import Connector
ImportError: No module named socketpool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/couchapp", line 7, in <module>
    from couchapp.dispatch import run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 10, in <module>
    import couchapp.commands as commands
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/commands.py", line 15, in <module>
    from couchapp import clone_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/clone_app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from couchapp.errors import AppError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/couchapp/errors.py", line 7, in <module>
    from restkit import ResourceError
ImportError: cannot import name ResourceError
```

As far as I understand the error is:

```
ImportError: No module named socketpool
```

How can I install this module or how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have pip installeded. If not install it using a package manager such as apt-get and thereafter using pip you can install socketpool.

Comment: Thank you. After installing pip and socketpool it works!

Comment: Perhaps I can convert it to an answer and you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

As Ifthikhan sugessted: Install it using a package manager such as apt-get and thereafter using pip you can install socketpool.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when installing couchapp. I used pip to install it, and I thought it completed, but when I ran it I had the ImportError problem. Turns out the pip install didn't succeed and I first needed to:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Then when I did a

```
pip install couchapp
```

all of the dependencies were installed and couchapp ran without a problem.